# Dynamic translation, Angular and PHP

Tags: php, angular

I am working on an existing project assigned to me by a client. What I have a problem with are dynamic translations.

Backend:
backend\src\Bundle\ApiBundle\Resources\translations\en_translation_file.yml

```
table:
  morning: Good morning %name%
```

backend\src\Bundle\ApiBundle\Resources\translations\rs_translation_file.yml

```
table:
  morning: Dobro jutro %name%
```

So for every language, there is the translation for it, this %name% need to be sent from the frontend because that is user input, and I have issue how to pass it to the backend

Frontend:

names.component.html

```
<em>{{ trans.table.morning | translate }}</em>
```

\web\dashboard\src\app\shared\translations.ts

```
morning : translate('trans.table.morning '),
```

So the issue is that the user can insert a name from the code from names.omponent.html, but my issue is how to pass dynamic value to the backend, any help?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to send to the backend the translated sentence with the placeholder (`%name%`) filled with the user input ?

You can use the `TranslateService` ([see doc](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods)) in your component to get the full sentence then send it to the backend using `HttpClient` with a REST API for example.